# "Manifest" folder is missing after creating a new project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm working with Eclipse and opened a "Android Application Project".
At the activity choosing point, I chose "Blank Activity".
I'm following this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html
And at the point that they're asking to go to "AndroidManifest.xml" file in the "manifest" folder, but that folder desn't exist.

How can I import it?
TNX!

Answer (score 0):

1.when you create a file you already have a file called manifest.xml.

2.and this is not a folder it is a file.

3.And If this file is not present delete the project and start again.

I think this would help